ssrs group label repeating on the next page
I have a table that I’m grouping by office(outermost/leftmost group) and employee (inner group). It has a page break after office, but when some employee rows(within the same group) extend to the next page, the office and employee group label is displayed again(on the same line). How do I prevent them from printing?
I tried going into advanced mode and setting repeatOnNextpPage to “false” and keepWithgroup to “after” yet no luck.

Did the anser work for you?

Yea thanks. Did have to delete the additional grouping columns that were being added in the left. Those were the ones being repeated

When you are in your report design window, select the tablix.
At the bottom, you will see Row Group to your left and Column Group to your right.
At the very edge of Column Groups, there is a tiny downward pointing dropdown, click on that and select "Advanced Mode"

That will open you your Static Groups under your Row Groups.
Select the first one, and then go to properties. Set RepeatonNewPage = False

